# Android - Listview search inner-text by ignoring Case

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement "Listview with search" functionality, in which i am successful to search with the word that we trying to enter in the edittext. But i want to implement to search with inner-text from a string. for that i have tried to implement:

```
string.contains(txtSearch.getText().toString())
```

I am successful in this as well. But **there is a still problem of "Case sensivity", how do i search for inner-text with ignoring case ?**

Can you suggest me what should do i with **`Contains()`** to ignore case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to temporarily convert both 'sides' to upper- or lowercase:

```
string.toLowerCase().contains(txtSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much faster (in my experience) to use regexp:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(txtSearch.getText().toString()), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("");
// ... for each string:
m.reset(string);
m.find(); // returns true if the text of txtSearch is found inside string
```

Comment: but can you please let me know by which way it is much faster?